# Is cake donut mix the same as all purpose flour?

Tags: baking, substitutions, flour, baking-soda, baking-powder

Was gifted [a 50lb bag of cake donut mix](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/pillsbury-50-lb-elite-raised-donut-mix/108991505.html) and my kids wanted to learn how to make donuts. All the recipes we've researched call for all purpose flour and I couldn't find a definitive if this cake mix can be a 100% replacement for all purpose flour or if cake mix was an equivalent to bisquick which contains a multitude of ingredients.

So my question is: can cake donut mix be a replacement for all purpose flour, or do I need to remove something along with it?

Comment: Do you have information on what brand the cake donut mix is? It's possible that it could be "just add water" mix, but the answer for how to use your mix would vary depending on brand/manufacturer

Comment: This is it: https://www.webstaurantstore.com/pillsbury-50-lb-elite-raised-donut-mix/108991505.html

Comment: The link points to *raised* donut mix, which is different from *cake* donut mix. But the description contains the directions for use: water, yeast, and the mix. There's additionally a link on that page to nutrition information that includes the ingredient list for everything contained in the mix.

Comment: What are the ingredients on the bag?

Comment: The link you posted points to a page with a PDF called "nutrition" that has not only the ingredients, but cooking instructions

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, this mix is not the same as all-purpose flour.

This product is meant to be the whole of your dry ingredients in the donut recipe and is designed to be used with water, as it contains powdered whey and milk powders, as well as fats.  It does not seem to include leaveners and so requires either baking powder/soda or yeast, which the instructions mention.

Following the instructions provided with the product is a good bet your first time, however, you should be able to elaborate on the recipe if you like, adding filled ingredients like cream or jam and things that get mixed into your dough, like blueberries or chocolate chips, etc...